# Incorrect coordinates on svg to canvas conversion

Tags: svg, fabricjs

I am trying to convert SVG image to canvas (and after that to PNG) using fabricjs.
It works, but looks like I miss some important params

You can see result of conversion here
http://staging.chiplab.com/test/1.html
And original svg http://staging.chiplab.com/test/1.svg

Code that I am using for conversion:

```
<script src="https://staging.chiplab.com/test/fabric.js" data-cover></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas> 
<script>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('https://staging.chiplab.com/test/1.svg', function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});    
</script>
```

Looks like for some reason when browser parse svg, it position image relative to parent block

```
   <svg id="fore" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="none" style="pointer-events:none">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" style="pointer-events:inherit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://staging.chiplab.com/media/uploads/dol/2/147751672809184826599.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="rotate(0,278.0784,278.0784)"></image>
    </svg>
```

However, when parse with fabricjs, image position to 0:0 coordinates.
I think that fabricjs has possibility to avoid such behaviour, but I can not find it in the docs.

Thank you everyone for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Somve svg features are unsupported.
This SVG has text on a path and some other feature that fabricjs still cannot parse.
if you want to convert to image, load it as an image. and paint it over the canvas.

There seems to be loading issue from your domain from this svg, something related to crossOrigin or internal svg parts.

```js
string = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" xlinkns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="791" height="593.0568" x="540" y="600" overflow="visible"> <defs> <filter id="canvashadow" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"> <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4" result="blur"></feGaussianBlur> <feOffset in="blur" dx="1" dy="1" result="offsetBlur"></feOffset> <feMerge> <feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> </feMerge> </filter> </defs> <svg id="canvasBackground" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="none" style="pointer-events:none"> <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="#FFF" style="pointer-events:none" filter="url(#canvashadow)"></rect> <pattern id="gridpattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"> <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></image> </pattern> </svg> <svg id="Blueprint" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="none" style="pointer-events:none"> <image x="0" y="0" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" style="pointer-events:inherit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://staging.chiplab.com/js/all/editor/images/blank.gif" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="rotate(0,278.0784,278.0784)"></image> </svg> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" id="svgcontent" overflow="hidden" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" viewBox="0 0 150.72 150.72"> <rect id="colorRect" width="150.72" height="150.72" x="0" y="0" fill="url(#svg_27)" style="pointer-events:none"></rect> <g style="pointer-events:all"> <title style="pointer-events:inherit">Layer 1</title> <image x="30.4878" y="30.4878" width="89.74439" height="89.74439" id="svg_34" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xlink:href="http://staging.chiplab.com/media/uploads/dol/2/1477839290025450446210.png" resized="true" imagetype="image1" style="pointer-events:inherit"></image> <g id="svg_6" class="clipart_img" attr_c="clipart_img" attr_aspt="aspect" style="pointer-events:inherit"> <path d="M75.36,31.36C99.56,31.36 119.26,51.06 119.26,75.26S99.56,119.26 75.36,119.26S31.36,99.56 31.36,75.36S51.16,31.36 75.36,31.36M75.36,11.56C40.16,11.56 11.56,40.16 11.56,75.36S40.16,139.16 75.36,139.16S139.16,110.56 139.16,75.36S110.56,11.56 75.36,11.56L75.36,11.56z" id="svg_5" fill="url(#svg_30)" style="pointer-events:inherit"></path> </g> <g id="svg_14" class="clipart_img" attr_c="clipart_img" attr_aspt="aspect" fill-opacity="0.6" style="pointer-events:inherit"> <path d="M72.56,139.16C70.56,139.16 68.76,138.96 66.96,138.66L69.46,119.46C70.86,119.66 72.16,119.66 73.56,119.96L72.56,139.16zM78.16,139.16L77.26,119.66C78.66,119.66 79.96,119.46 81.36,119.16L84.06,138.36C81.96,138.86 80.16,139.16 78.16,139.16zM61.26,137.76C59.46,137.26 57.66,136.86 55.86,136.16L61.76,117.66C63.16,118.16 64.26,118.36 65.56,118.76L61.26,137.76zM89.46,137.76L85.16,118.76C86.56,118.56 87.66,118.06 88.96,117.66L95.06,136.16C93.26,136.66 91.46,137.26 89.46,137.76zM50.36,134.16C48.56,133.46 46.96,132.56 45.16,131.66L54.46,114.46C55.56,115.16 56.76,115.56 58.06,116.26L50.36,134.16zM100.56,134.16L92.86,116.26C93.96,115.76 95.36,115.16 96.46,114.46L105.76,131.46C103.86,132.56 102.06,133.46 100.56,134.16zM40.26,128.76C38.66,127.66 37.06,126.46 35.76,125.36L47.76,110.16C48.86,111.06 49.76,111.76 50.96,112.46L40.26,128.76zM110.46,128.76L99.56,112.66C100.66,111.96 101.86,111.06 102.76,110.36L114.76,125.56C113.56,126.46 112.06,127.56 110.46,128.76zM31.16,121.66C29.76,120.26 28.46,118.96 27.36,117.56L42.06,104.66C42.96,105.56 43.86,106.66 44.76,107.56L31.16,121.66zM119.46,121.46L106.16,107.46C107.06,106.56 107.96,105.66 108.86,104.56L123.56,117.26C122.16,118.76 120.86,120.36 119.46,121.46zM23.76,113.06C22.66,111.46 21.46,109.86 20.56,108.36L37.06,98.36C37.76,99.46 38.46,100.66 39.36,101.76L23.76,113.06zM126.96,112.86L111.36,101.56C112.06,100.46 112.96,99.26 113.66,98.16L130.36,108.16C128.96,109.76 128.06,111.26 126.96,112.86zM17.86,103.16C16.96,101.36 16.26,99.76 15.56,97.96L33.66,91.16C34.16,92.26 34.56,93.66 35.26,94.76L17.86,103.16zM132.76,103.16L115.36,94.76C116.06,93.66 116.46,92.26 116.96,91.16L135.06,97.96C134.36,99.56 133.66,101.36 132.76,103.16zM13.86,92.56C13.36,90.76 12.96,88.96 12.46,86.86L31.46,83.46C31.66,84.86 31.96,85.96 32.36,87.26L13.86,92.56zM136.86,92.26L118.16,87.06C118.66,85.66 118.86,84.56 119.06,83.26L138.06,86.66C137.76,88.66 137.36,90.46 136.86,92.26zM11.76,81.26C11.56,79.46 11.56,77.36 11.56,75.56L30.96,75.56C30.96,76.96 30.96,78.26 31.16,79.66L11.76,81.26zM138.86,81.26L119.46,79.46C119.46,78.36 119.66,76.96 119.66,75.66L119.66,75.16L139.06,75.16C139.16,77.36 138.86,79.16 138.86,81.26zM31.16,71.46L12.06,69.96C12.26,68.16 12.56,66.16 12.76,64.26L31.76,67.66C31.46,68.76 31.16,70.16 31.16,71.46zM119.46,71.26C119.26,69.86 119.26,68.56 118.96,67.46L137.96,63.86C138.46,65.66 138.66,67.66 138.66,69.56L119.46,71.26zM32.56,63.56L13.86,58.56C14.36,56.76 14.96,54.96 15.66,53.16L33.76,59.96C33.26,61.06 32.76,62.46 32.56,63.56zM118.16,63.36C117.66,61.96 117.46,60.86 116.76,59.56L134.86,52.56C135.56,54.36 136.26,56.16 136.66,57.96L118.16,63.36zM35.26,56.16L17.86,47.76C18.76,45.96 19.66,44.36 20.56,42.76L37.26,52.76C36.36,53.86 35.96,54.96 35.26,56.16zM115.16,55.86C114.46,54.76 114.06,53.56 113.36,52.46L129.86,42.46C130.76,44.06 131.66,45.86 132.56,47.46L115.16,55.86zM39.36,49.36L23.76,38.06C24.86,36.46 26.06,35.16 27.36,33.56L42.06,46.26C40.86,47.26 39.96,48.16 39.36,49.36zM111.16,49.06C110.46,47.96 109.56,47.06 108.66,45.86L123.06,32.96C124.46,34.36 125.56,35.86 126.66,37.46L111.16,49.06zM44.56,43.46L31.06,29.46C32.46,28.06 33.76,26.96 35.36,25.66L47.56,40.86C46.56,41.66 45.46,42.56 44.56,43.46zM105.96,43.26C105.06,42.36 103.96,41.46 103.06,40.56L115.06,25.36C116.66,26.46 117.96,27.86 119.36,29.16L105.96,43.26zM50.86,38.46L39.96,22.46C41.56,21.36 43.16,20.46 44.96,19.56L54.26,36.56C53.06,36.86 51.96,37.56 50.86,38.46zM99.56,38.26C98.46,37.56 97.26,36.86 96.16,36.26L105.16,19.06C106.76,19.96 108.56,20.86 110.16,21.96L99.56,38.26zM57.86,34.66L50.16,16.76C51.96,16.06 53.76,15.36 55.56,14.76L61.66,33.26C60.06,33.46 58.96,33.96 57.86,34.66zM92.66,34.36C91.56,33.86 90.16,33.46 88.86,32.96L94.76,14.46C96.56,15.16 98.36,15.86 100.16,16.46L92.66,34.36zM65.26,32.16L60.96,13.16C62.76,12.66 64.56,12.46 66.56,12.06L69.26,31.26C67.76,31.46 66.66,31.66 65.26,32.16zM84.96,32.16C83.56,31.96 82.46,31.66 81.16,31.46L83.56,12.26C85.36,12.46 87.36,12.96 89.16,13.16L84.96,32.16zM73.16,31.06L72.26,11.56C73.36,11.56 74.26,11.56 75.46,11.56C76.36,11.56 77.26,11.56 78.16,11.56L77.26,31.06C76.56,31.06 75.86,31.06 75.26,31.06C74.56,31.06 73.86,31.06 73.16,31.06z" id="svg_13" fill="#ffffff" style="pointer-events:inherit"></path> </g> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" d="M19.12221,50.96975C19.12221,33.37442 33.37443,19.12221 50.96975,19.12221C68.56508,19.12221 82.81729,33.37443 82.81729,50.96975C82.81729,68.56508 68.56507,82.81729 50.96975,82.81729C33.37442,82.81729 19.12221,68.56507 19.12221,50.96975z" id="svg_18" visibility="hidden" display="none" textpath="true" clipid="svg_19" style="pointer-events:inherit"></path> <text texttype="text1" template_text="true" id="svg_20" font-size="9pt" font_size="9pt" font-family="Anton" text_type="textpath" clipid="svg_19" pathid="svg_18" x="0" fill="#000000" isMultiline="false" text-anchor="middle" ascent="1.1875" descent="0.1875" leading="0" transform="rotate(-90 75.47694396972658,50.96131896972657) " font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="pointer-events:inherit"> <textPath xlink:href="#svg_19" startOffset="50%" font_size="null" x="0" style="pointer-events:inherit"> <tspan id="svg_1" xml:space="preserve" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" font-family="Anton" font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="pointer-events:inherit">Gabe s Poker Room</tspan> </textPath> </text> <text texttype="text2" fill="#000000" stroke-width="0" x="75.36867" y="110.59035" id="svg_24" text-anchor="middle" xml:space="preserve" font-family="Anton" isMultiline="true" font_size="20pt" line-spacing="0" aspect="true" template_text="true" resized="false" attr_rs="false" font-size="20pt" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" text-decoration="none" style="pointer-events:inherit"><tspan xml:space="preserve" id="svg_12" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" font-family="Anton" font-size="20pt" text-decoration="none" dy="0" x="75.36867" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal" style="pointer-events:inherit">5</tspan></text> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5" style="pointer-events:inherit"></feGaussianBlur> </g> <defs> <path d="M19.12221,50.96975C19.12221,33.37442 33.37443,19.12221 50.96975,19.12221C68.56508,19.12221 82.81729,33.37443 82.81729,50.96975C82.81729,68.56508 68.56507,82.81729 50.96975,82.81729C33.37442,82.81729 19.12221,68.56507 19.12221,50.96975z" fill="none" id="svg_19"></path> <radialGradient id="svg_27" spreadMethod="pad" cy="0.5"> <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0"></stop> <stop stop-color="#C8102E" stop-opacity="0.99609" offset="1"></stop> </radialGradient> <radialGradient id="svg_30" spreadMethod="pad" cy="0.5"> <stop stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="0.99609" offset="0"></stop> <stop stop-color="#C8102E" stop-opacity="0.99609" offset="1"></stop> </radialGradient> <filter id="grayscale"> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> </filter> <filter id="glow"> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"></feGaussianBlur> <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0.8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix"></feColorMatrix> <feGaussianBlur result="coloredBlur" stdDeviation="2.5"></feGaussianBlur> <feMerge id="merges"> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"></feMergeNode> <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode> </feMerge> </filter> <filter id="sepia"> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix> <feColorMatrix values="0.30 0.30 0.30 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0 0 0.20 0.20 0.20 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic"></feColorMatrix> </filter> </defs> </svg> <svg id="canvasBleed1" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="none" style="display:none"> <rect id="backrect1" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="10 8" stroke="#00ff00" fill="none" style="pointer-events:none"></rect> <rect id="textrect1" width="45px" height="8px" x="0" y="0" fill="#00ff00" style="pointer-events:none"></rect> <text id="bleedText1" x="1" y="6" font-size="8px" font-family="Arial" fill="#ffffff" style="pointer-events:none">safe margin</text> </svg> <svg id="canvasGrid" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="visible" display="none"> <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" fill="url(#gridpattern)" style="pointer-events: none; display:visible;"></rect> </svg> <svg id="fore" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="none" style="pointer-events:none"> <image x="0" y="0" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" style="pointer-events:inherit" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://staging.chiplab.com/media/uploads/dol/2/147751672809184826599.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="rotate(0,278.0784,278.0784)"></image> </svg> <g id="selectorParentGroup" transform="translate(117.42160000000001,18.45)"> <g display="none"> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_nw" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:nw-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_n" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:n-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_ne" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:ne-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_e" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:e-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_se" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:se-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_s" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:s-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_sw" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:sw-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <rect id="selectorGrip_resize_w" fill="#2c9ff8" width="12" height="12" style="cursor:w-resize" stroke="#222" pointer-events="all"></rect> <line id="selectorGrip_rotateconnector" stroke="#000"></line> <circle id="selectorGrip_rotate" fill="#2c9ff8" r="10" stroke="#222" stroke-width="2" style="cursor:url(/js/all/editor/images/rotate.png) 12 12, auto;"></circle> </g> <rect id="selectorRubberBand" fill="#22C" fill-opacity="0.15" stroke="#22C" stroke-width="0.5" display="none" style="pointer-events:none" x="619.0784054331419" y="89.5500000724083" width="0" height="0"></rect> </g> <svg id="canvasBleed" width="556.1568" height="556.1568" x="117.42160000000001" y="18.45" overflow="none" style="display:none"> <rect id="backrect" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" stroke-dasharray="10 8" stroke="#ff0000" fill="none" stroke-width="2" style="pointer-events:none"></rect> <rect id="textrect" width="40px" height="8px" x="0" y="0" stroke="#ff0000" fill="#ff0000" style="pointer-events:none"></rect> <text id="bleedText" x="1" y="6" font-size="8px" font-family="Arial" fill="#ffffff" style="pointer-events:none">cut margin</text> </svg> </svg>'

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromString(string, function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  canvas.add(obj);
});

var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');
var image = new fabric.Image(document.getElementById('plainimage'));
canvas2.add(image);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js" ></script>

<img id="plainimage" src="//staging.chiplab.com/test/1.svg" />

As SVG
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
As an image
<canvas id="canvas2" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```